# Were Dementor effects targeted?

Tags: harry-potter, magical-creatures

Dementors seemed to have had some distance effects on humans - the feeling of coldness, moral depression, darkness.

Is there canon evidence that these area effects were **targeted** at specific individuals (or that Dementors excluded individuals from such effects)?

Or was the effect 100% determined by distance of Dementor and the individual's personal "Dementor resistance"?